# Powershell send out email to users expiration of access

Tags: powershell

Okay so I have these users in a MSSQL database and I have the last time they logged in epoc time, does anybody know how to script something in powershell to notify user if they have not logged in for more than 30 days? I also have their email addresses stored in the database as well. If anybody could give me some guidance.

```
# clear log file
"######ERROR LOG File######" | Out-File $ErrorFileName
 Get-Date -Format G | Add-Content $ErrorFileName
"####################" | Add-Content $ErrorFileName


#For loop giving variables to the objects
$objs = $Json.users
foreach($obj in $objs)
    {

Try {

        $userID = $obj.userID
        $shortName = $obj.shortName
        $firstname = $obj.firstName
        $lastname = $obj.lastName
        $email = $obj.email
        $active =$obj.active
        $lastActivationTimestamp = $obj.lastActivationTimestamp

        
        Write-Host ($obj.userID) -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor darkblue
        Write-Host ($obj.shortName) -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor darkblue
        Write-Host ($obj.firstName) -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor red
        Write-Host ($obj.lastName) -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor red
        Write-Host ($obj.email) -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor red
        Write-Host ($obj.active) -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor black
        Write-Host ($obj.lastActivationTimestamp) -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor black





#Inserting into MYSQL database
            $cmd = $connection.CreateCommand()
            $insert_stmt = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users]([userID],[userName],[firstName],[lastName],[email],[Active],[lastActivationTimestamp])
                                VALUES ('$userID','$shortName','$firstname','$lastname','$email','$active','$lastActivationTimestamp')" -replace "\s+"," "
            $cmd.CommandText = $insert_stmt
            write-host $insert_stmt -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor DarkBlue
            $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


                                    } Catch {
  # Error TYPE
  "[$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)]" | Add-Content $ErrorFileName
  # Error MESSAGE
  $_.Exception.Message | Add-Content $ErrorFileName
  $ROW[0] | Add-Content $ErrorFileName
    
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: Sure. I cut the credentials and other stuff to access the database, but here is the rest of the code.

Comment: I commend to your attention the output of [Get-Help Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah i know how to send the email out. I just dont know how to code to compare the epoc time and tell me that is been almost 30 days since last log in and send email to that user.

Comment: Please edit your question to make clear what your actual issue is - the way it is currently written, it appeared that you were unknowledgeable about the send-mail part, not the calculate-expiration part.